# The reciprocal matrix of positive semidefinite matrix is also positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{n\times n}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix,and each element is positive. Is the matrix 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{a_{ij}}\right)_{n\times n}
$$
also a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: Hint: check if this is true for $2\times 2$ matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a &b\\b&a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not correct for instance 
$$A=
\left (\begin{array}[cc]
11&1/4 \\
1/4&1
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then $|A|=15/16>0$

But if you denote $B$ the matrix with the reciprocal entries then
$|B|= -15.$